# Meteor full production web app load/stress testing?

Tags: meteor, jmeter, load-testing

I need to do load testing for my full fledged multi routes, stateful web app. There are options like meteor-down and meteor-load-test but they are not testing exact user behavior which includes everything from server code to client code.

Or I should test only server side code as this is which is gonna to run on server as everything else will run on client? 
And how can I test other routes within my Meteor app or testing only root path is sufficient. I also need benchmarking of different parameters regarding testing.

Can I also use other stress testing tool like Jmeter or not? And in case meteor-down and meteor-load-test are the best option can you provide some scenarios(prototype code) to test for.

Please guide me for stress testing related to meteor.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced from the same problem but after doing some R&D I have found out the solution for it .
First, you need to find out how your application behaves under heavy load .For that you need to find which  are the methods you can load test .
lets take
 eg I have to test concurrency users against my meteor app .
 use ddp-client for accessing meteor server . there are severals of ddp-clients available you can choose as per user need . 
I have taken node js DDP-client . created web services for it . for creating web services I have used an express framework . once your web services are ready then you can create JMeter load script for same then you are done . if you start giving load on deloped web services ultimately  you are giving load on meteor server .

bullet points are as follows :

```
1. create node app
2. use DDP-client for accessing meteor methods 
3. use express framework to create  web services 
4. create Load script for those web services using Jmeter
```

I am gonna create detail steps ( with some project ) blog  for it . till the time this might help you or give direction

Comment: Thanks yogesh. I will definitely try out as you specified.